# Why Would A Function Call Place its First Argument into CPU Register RDX?

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

As I stepped through some new code in one of my libraries, I noticed that the first argument appears to be going into the RDX register instead of the documented RCX register. Though hardly a world-ending catastrophe, I am curious; why might this be so, unless RCX is being set aside to pass a reference to **this**, as happens in C++. As well, it may be significant that the routine being called is a **static** method on the instance.

Following is the disassembly of the entire function, which is a very basic syntactic sugar function.

```
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pastrAdditionalMessages">
        /// Pass in the optional list of additonal messages if needed. Status
        /// codes zero and one are covered by stanard messages that are pulled
        /// from the resource strings stored in WizardWrx.Common.dll.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The total number of messages is as described under <paramref name="pastrAdditionalMessages"/>.
        /// </returns>
        private static int ComputeMessageCount ( string [ ] pastrAdditionalMessages )
        {
00007FFED9688940  push        rbp  
00007FFED9688941  push        rdi  
00007FFED9688942  push        rsi  
00007FFED9688943  sub         rsp,30h  
00007FFED9688947  mov         rbp,rsp  
00007FFED968894A  mov         rsi,rcx  
00007FFED968894D  lea         rdi,[rbp+20h]  
00007FFED9688951  mov         ecx,4  
00007FFED9688956  xor         eax,eax  
00007FFED9688958  rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]  
00007FFED968895A  mov         rcx,rsi  
00007FFED968895D  mov         qword ptr [rbp+50h],rcx  
00007FFED9688961  cmp         dword ptr [7FFED95791F8h],0  
00007FFED9688968  je          WizardWrx.ConsoleAppAids3.ConsoleAppStateManager.ComputeMessageCount(System.String[])+02Fh (07FFED968896Fh)  
00007FFED968896A  call        00007FFF390CCBA0  
00007FFED968896F  nop  
            return pastrAdditionalMessages == null ? STANDARD_MESSAGE_COUNT : pastrAdditionalMessages.Length + STANDARD_MESSAGE_COUNT;
00007FFED9688970  cmp         qword ptr [rbp+50h],0  
00007FFED9688975  je          WizardWrx.ConsoleAppAids3.ConsoleAppStateManager.ComputeMessageCount(System.String[])+046h (07FFED9688986h)  
00007FFED9688977  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+50h]  
00007FFED968897B  mov         eax,dword ptr [rax+8]  
00007FFED968897E  add         eax,2  
00007FFED9688981  mov         dword ptr [rbp+20h],eax  
00007FFED9688984  jmp         WizardWrx.ConsoleAppAids3.ConsoleAppStateManager.ComputeMessageCount(System.String[])+04Dh (07FFED968898Dh)  
00007FFED9688986  mov         dword ptr [rbp+20h],2  
00007FFED968898D  mov         eax,dword ptr [rbp+20h]  
00007FFED9688990  mov         dword ptr [rbp+24h],eax  
00007FFED9688993  nop  
00007FFED9688994  jmp         WizardWrx.ConsoleAppAids3.ConsoleAppStateManager.ComputeMessageCount(System.String[])+056h (07FFED9688996h)  
        }   // private static int ComputeMessageCount
00007FFED9688996  mov         eax,dword ptr [rbp+24h]  
00007FFED9688999  lea         rsp,[rbp+30h]  
00007FFED968899D  pop         rsi  
00007FFED968899E  pop         rdi  
00007FFED968899F  pop         rbp  
00007FFED96889A0  ret
```

Comment: Where is `rdx` used in your decompiled code?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't doing what you think - here in the preamble :

```
00007FFED9688940  push        rbp       // SAVE RBP
00007FFED9688941  push        rdi       // SAVE RDI
00007FFED9688942  push        rsi       // SAVING RSI
00007FFED9688943  sub         rsp,30h   // ADD STACK SPACE
00007FFED9688947  mov         rbp,rsp   // SAVE STACK POINTER
00007FFED968894A  mov         rsi,rcx   // SAVING RCX - (Already contains your string[] argument)
00007FFED968894D  lea         rdi,[rbp+20h]  
00007FFED9688951  mov         ecx,4  
00007FFED9688956  xor         eax,eax  
00007FFED9688958  rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]  // STACK OPS ^^^
00007FFED968895A  mov         rcx,rsi  // *****  HERE Moving string[] back to RCX in preparation for the call
00007FFED968895D  mov         qword ptr [rbp+50h],rcx  
00007FFED9688961  cmp         dword ptr [7FFED95791F8h],0  
00007FFED9688968  je          WizardWrx.ConsoleAppAids3.ConsoleAppStateManager.ComputeMessageCount(System.String[])+02Fh (07FFED968896Fh)  
00007FFED968896A  call        00007FFF390CCBA0
```

Prior to calling the function it seems your string array is already living in RCX.  Prior to the method call the caller saves RBP, RDI, and RSI, then adds stack space and saves its current RCX pointer to RSI (will pop after the function returns).

Following this there are some stack operations and then arguments get set up for the call - only one, so `mov rcx, rsi` - your array pointer is going into RCX, as expected.  RDX appears nowhere in this disassembly.